# Detect change in input element, set with JavaScript

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a slider connected to an input element. I have no control on the slider implementation. Whenever the slider is moved, the input element value is updated. I can check that with `$('#my-input').val()`

But, as documented [here](https://api.jquery.com/change/), I am not able to detect that change with the `.change()` event handler, because JavaScript manipulation of the input's value does not trigger that event.

My question is: how can I detect that the value in my input element has changed? What event - if any - is triggered in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect input value change made by jQuery function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997079/detect-input-value-change-made-by-jquery-function)

Answer (score 0):

It'd be good to see a code example so we could understand what events would be taking place on which elements whilst the slider is being moved, but it should be something along the lines of:

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.slider-handle',function(){
    curVal = $('input').val();
});
```

You'll need to replace `.slider-handle` with a selector appropriate to the slider you are using, `mousedown` might need changing also, depending on which events you want to hook onto

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to detect:

```
function addClassNameListener(elemId, callback) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  var lastClassName = elem.className;
  window.setInterval( function() {   
    var className = elem.className;
    if (className !== lastClassName) {
      callback();   
      lastClassName = className;
    }
  },10);
}
```

Usage:

```
addClassNameListener("moved", function(){
  // do something...
})
// This code will listem all classes that contains "moved" classname and callback that function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI for the slider functionality, the change event will fire on the slider element instead of the input.

```
$('.slider').slider(); //init jQuery UI slider
$('.slider').on('slidechange', function(event, ui) {
    var newVal = ui.value;

    //do something when the value changes
});
```

You can read more about this and other events on the jQuery UI page: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

You also have access to events like `slide` and `slidestop` which might be more appropriate for your solution.